# Bolts Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, ld, bolts-framework

```
duplicate symbol _BFMeasurementEventArgsKey in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkParseEventName in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateInEventName in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateOutEventName in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateBackToReferrerEventName in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/BaselFarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TokenApp-dqdwcnpmpvwcdadwwxpinxtlvuoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-TokenApp-Bolts.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/BaselFarag/Desktop/src/tokenapp/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I understand that there are duplicates in my files and that's why I'm receiving this error (at least that what I think it the problem according to the ld). What I don't know how to do is reconcile the multiple files. I tried just removing Bolt entirely but that just made Xcode angry. REAL angry. Any help on how to solve this one? I'm pretty sure this is an easy one but I'm a noob.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?, did you tried removing it from Podfile and then use "pod install" to remove it?

Comment: Well that's the weird thing, I didn't add Bolts to the Cocoapods. It may have been accidentally added when I installed Parse. Is there a way I can remove it from my project via Cocoapods if it wasn't installed using Cocoapods? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: How did you installed Parse?

Comment: By adding it to the directory. I did not use Cocoapods.

Comment: I really suggest you switch to cocoapods, remove the folder and the  library links of the project, follow the "tutorial" in http://cocoapods.org/ to install them, add parse pod: "'Parse', '~> 1.6'", cocoapods are awesome, they manage all the dependencies and ensure that you will not have duplicates. I know I'm not answering you question directly, but everybody loves cocoapods for a reason :)

Comment: Yeah I'm using Cocoapods already but I think you've actually answered my question indirectly hahah. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Starting from scratch and installing everything via Cocoapods solved the issue. Warning to other peeps: Do not install a framework manually then try to use Cocoapods. Just use it from the get go, otherwise Pods will not check for duplicates.

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer, since I had the same problem and almost overlooked that there is a solution for this!!

Comment: You got it! Just gimme until I get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for future consultation:

What solved my issue in the end was starting from scratch and installing my dependencies via Cocoapods. It appears if you try to add a framework via a drag and drop and then later user= Cocoapods the previous framework will not be noticed by Cocoapods and Cocoapods will attempt to install that very same framework again.

So when using dependencies either only use drag and drop or only use Cocoapods from the get go. Do not try to mix and match.